# Use of Black-Scholes Model on Guaranteed Fund Investment

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

I am stuck with a revision question at home on Black-Scholes pricing model.

The question is on a fund manager selling one unit of the fund to a customer for $S(0)$ at time $0$ and then guaranteeing at time T to pay customer maximum of $S(0)$ or $e^{-aT}  S(T)$ for $a>0$ being the fund fee. The model I read about talks about maximum of $S(T)-K$ or $0$.

How can one value the customer pay-off at time $0$ or time t?

Comment: Changed $e^(-at) x S(T)$ to $e^{-aT} S(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

you can just transform the payoff into a form that becomes a linear combination of the ordinary black scholes:

$max(S(0), e^{-aT} S(T))$ = $S(0) + e^{-at}max(0, S(T) - S(0)e^{aT})$
this equals $S(0) + constant * max(0, S(T)- K)$ where $K = S(0)e^{aT}$.

The option you can value with regular black scholes, then just scale it etc.